# Rendering Partial View NopCommerce Plugins

Tags: partial-views, nopcommerce

I'm working on to write a new payment plugin on nopcommerce.

How can I render a new partialview in PaymentInfo.cshtml? The new view locates the same path with PaymentInfo.cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

to render any view in the plugins for nopCommerce it must be embedded resource and it must be written in fully qualified name like

```
@Html.Partial("Nop.Plugin.Something.Something.Views.Plugin.VIEWNAME", item)
```

Comment: so add some more code to check where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Custom View Engine and add that to your payment plugin. This so you can add routes to Nopcommerce.

First you create a Custom View Engine

CustomViewEngine.cs

```
public class CustomViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
    {
        public CustomViewEngine()
        {
            PartialViewLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Plugins/Misc.HelloWorld/Views/{0}.cshtml" };
            ViewLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Plugins/Misc.HelloWorld/Views/{0}.cshtml" };

        }
    }
```

Change paths of the Misc.Helloworld to the path of your plugin.

Change the .Edit to the action in your controller.

Change the other information of the controller and the action to the names in your plugin.

After that, create a RouteProvider.cs

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Insert(0, new CustomViewEngine());


        var route = routes.MapRoute("Plugin.Misc.HelloWorld.Edit",
             new { controller = "HelloWorld", action = "Edit",  }, 
             new { },
             new[] { "Nop.Plugin.Misc.HelloWorld.Controllers" }
        );
        routes.Remove(route);
        routes.Insert(0, route);
```

Change Misc.HelloWorld to the path of your Payment.Plugin, 
After that u can add the following to the embedded source

```
@Html.Partial("Actionname", item)
```

For more information, see the blog of [Alex Wolf](http://alexwolfthoughts.com/overriding-nopcommerce-admin-views-and-partial-views/)